# Question on Euler's summation formula

Tags: analysis, number-theory

Proof from Apostol: (Annotations mine)

If $f$ has a continuous derivative $f'$ on the interval $[y, x]$, where $0 < y < x$, then

$$\sum\limits_{y < n \le x} f(n) = \int_y^x f(t) dt  + \int_y^x(t - [t]) f'(t) dt$$
$$ + f(x)([x] - x) - f(y)([y] - y) \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

Proof: Let $m = [y], k = [x]$. For integers $n$ and $n-1$ in [y,x] we have

$$\int_{n-1}^n [t]f'(t) dt =\int_{n-1}^n (n-1)f'(t)dt = (n-1)\{f(n) - f(n-1)\} $$
$$ = \{nf(n) - (n-1)f(n-1)\} - f(n) \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

Summing from $n = m+1$ to $k$, we find:

$$ \int_m^k [t]f'(t) dt = \sum\limits_{n=m+1}^k\{nf(n) - (n-1)f(n-1)\} -\sum\limits_{y<n\le x} f(n) \ \ \  (3)$$

Hence
$$\sum\limits_{y<n\le x} f(n) = -\int_m^k [t]f'(t) dt +kf(k) - mf(m)\ \ \ (4)$$
$$= -\int_m^k [t]f'(t) dt +kf(x) - mf(y) \ \ \ (5)$$

Integration by parts gives us:

$$\int_y^x f(t) dt = xf(x) - y f(y) - \int_y^x tf'(t) dt \ \ \ (6) $$

and when this is combined with $(5)$ we get $(1)$. End of Proof.

Questions: I understand most of the proof except for two things:

How could we go from $(4)$ to $(5)$, i.e., replace $f(k)$ by $f(x)$. Is this just an integer to real type conversion?

I don't get the last sentence of the proof, "and when this[referring to $(6)$] is combined with $(5)$ we get $(1)$". How?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the correct steps leading to the correct form of  (5) where the integration limits should be $x$ and $y$.

Starting with (2) which you obtained correctly,

$$\int_{n-1}^n [t]f'(t) dt  = \{nf(n) - (n-1)f(n-1)\}- f(n),$$

sum from $n = m+2$ to $k$ to obtain

$$\int_{m+1}^k [t]f'(t) dt = \sum\limits_{n=m+2}^k\{nf(n) - (n-1)f(n-1)\} -\sum_{n=m+2}^k f(n) \\ = kf(k) - (m+1)f(m+1) - \sum_{n=m+2}^k f(n) \\ =  kf(k) - mf(m+1) - \sum_{n=m+1}^k f(n).$$

Hence,

$$\sum_{y < n \leqslant x} f(n) = -\int_{m+1}^k [t]f'(t) dt +kf(k) - mf(m+1) \\ = -\int_{y}^x [t]f'(t) dt + \int_{k}^x [t]f'(t) dt + \int_{y}^{m+1} [t]f'(t) dt + kf(k) - mf(m+1) \\ =  -\int_{y}^x [t]f'(t) dt + kf(x) - kf(k) + mf(m+1) - mf(y) + kf(k) - mf(m+1),  $$

which implies

$$\tag{5}\sum_{y < n \leqslant x} f(n) = -\int_{y}^x [t]f'(t) dt + kf(x) - mf(y) $$

Now you should be able to complete the proof by subtracting (6) from (5).

Comment: Thank you. All this makes sense. I can see now that if we subtract (6) from (5) we now get (1). Good. But separate question. Why do we need to do that? Does (1) in that form have any advantage for further applications of this formula?

Comment: You're welcome.  Its just the first stage of the Euler-Maclaurin formula which can be used to approximate a sum with an integral (that may have a closed form) and reveal the asymptotic behavior of the sum as, for example, $x \to \infty$.  The remainder in this form can be expanded further if needed.  Suppose $f(n) = 1/n$ then we would find using this formula  that $\sum_{n=1}^m (1/n) = \log n + C +O(1/n)$ where $C$ is a constant (Euler-Mascheroni constant).